# Как добавить свой виджет на главное окно Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, графика, виджет

Создал свой виджет для визуализации круговой диаграммы:

.h файл

```
#ifndef PIECHART_H
#define PIECHART_H

#include <QWidget>

class PieChart : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit PieChart(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent*);
signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // PIECHART_H
```

.cpp файл

```
#include "piechart.h"
#include <QPainter>
PieChart::PieChart(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{

}

void PieChart::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) {
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
    painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt::black,Qt::BDiagPattern));
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::blue,4));
    painter.drawPie(QRect(10,10,110,70),90*16,270*16);
}
```

Как мне разместить его на главном окне программы? Насколько я понял нужен какой-то слой, в котором и будет размещен виджет(без этого слоя QPainter не работает). Я размещаю виджет в QGridLayout. Однако это не работает, программа в процессе работы выдает ошибку:

> QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on MainWindow
>   "MainWindow", which already has a layout

Код главного окна:

.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "piechart.h"
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    PieChart chart;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QGridLayout>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QGridLayout *l = new QGridLayout();
    l->addWidget(&chart);
    setLayout(l);
    chart.repaint();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Как мне правильно это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В дизайнере бросай на главное окно QWidget, затем преобразуй его к `PieChart`. Преобразование вызывается в контекстном меню.

Answer (score 2):

Если кроме этой диаграммы в окне ничего не будет, то лучше использовать `MainWindow::setCentralWidget(&chart)`. Идеология `Qt` предполагает использование указателей, так что лучше в классе задать `PieChart *chart;`